# iterating through a list of files to check how many lines are there inside

Tags: java, inputstream

I have been trying to write a simple code where i can go through a list of filenames, go through each file name, and calculate how many lines are there in each file.
However the code below doesn't seem to work at all (keeps initiating the debug perspective in eclipse).

```
public class fileScanner {

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    //add files
    list.add("C:\\Users\\HuiHui\\Documents\\eclipse\\test.txt");
    for (String l : list){
        fileScan(l);
    }

}

public static int fileScan(String filename) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
    try {
        byte[] c = new byte[1024];
        int count = 0;
        int readChars = 0;
        boolean endsWithoutNewLine = false;
        while ((readChars = is.read(c)) != -1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < readChars; ++i) {
                if (c[i] == '\n')
                    ++count;
            }
            endsWithoutNewLine = (c[readChars - 1] != '\n');
        }
        if(endsWithoutNewLine) {
            ++count;
        } 
        return count;
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }
}
```

}

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: **Universal first steps to fixing any problem**: 1) What is it supposed to do? (you've answered that already). 2) What does it actually do instead? (you haven't answered that)

Comment: @immibis it terminates by itself, making running it not possible at all.

Comment: What do you mean, "running it is not possible"?

Comment: I noticed that your code doesn't actually *do anything* with the number of lines, once it's counted them, btw.

Comment: @immibis it is supposed to run and give me the number of lines, whhich is stored in count, and at the end i returned count. but i am not sure as to whether that is right as well...

Comment: what do you want to do with the number of lines?

Comment: It sounds like you are running from Eclipse. I don't really understand what you say is happening, but do you accidentally have a breakpoint set somewhere, and you're running in debug mode?

Comment: @immibis just return the number of lines as an integer

Comment: @HanzawaNaoki well that's what you're already doing, so what's the problem?

Comment: @immibis it doesn't run and keeps terminating on its own, an i have no idea what happened...

Comment: @HanzawaNaoki how do you know it doesn't run?

Comment: @immibis it gives me a debug mode, and ask me to choose between terminate and run and theres no output

Comment: @HanzawaNaoki screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `LineNumberReader`:

```
public static int fileScan(String filename) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(filename);
    LineNumberReader lnr = null;
    try {
        lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(file));
        lnr.skip(file.length());//go to end of file
        return lnr.getLineNumber();
    } finally {
        if(null != lnr) {
            lnr.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This method accounts for empty lines as well right? how do u remove empty lines?

Comment: @HanzawaNaoki, you did not mentioned anything about blank line in your original post. BTW does it work for you apart from blank lines?

Comment: yes i did not mention about blank line, my bad. it was just a sudden question that came to my mind. and yes it works! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you're using `InputStream` and created a `BufferedInputStream` instead of using `BufferedReader` which does the job for you ?

try this for your `filescan` method

```
int filescan(String filename) throws IOException {
   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
   int count=0;
   String s;
   while((s=br.nextLine()) != null) 
       count++;
   br.close();
   return count;
}
```

Comment: hi there is some problems with nextLine() and they kept asking me to add a cast..?

Comment: yeah, sorry about that oversight, either cast br.nextLine() to string or store the value in a string.

Comment: Or you can basically use a one-liner (though it really should be wrapped in a try-with-resources): `return Files.lines(Paths.get(filename)).collect(Collectors.counting());`

Comment: Even better. TIL. Java 8 ?

Comment: Yes, that uses a bunch of Java 8 features. (And it would have to return a `long`, not an `int`)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to iterate through each file, and then increment an integer for every line that there is.

Example:

```
while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    scanner.nextLine();
    integer++;
}
```